# Mocha Chai: Deep include an array of objects, but only have part of expected object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm using the `assert` syntax of chai for this.

I know that if I want to check an array of objects for a specific object, I can do this:

```
assert.deepInclude(
  [
    { name: 'foo', id: 1 },
    { name: 'bar', id: 2 }
  ], 
  { name: 'foo', id: 1 }
)
```

Which should pass.

But what if I only have 1 property in the object that I'm checking for...? Like this:

```
assert.deepInclude(
  [
    { name: 'foo', id: 1 },
    { name: 'bar', id: 2 }
  ], 
  { name: 'foo' }
)
```

I still want this to pass, but it's telling me it's failing because that exact object does not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [chai-subset](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-subset) this can be done pretty easily:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiSubset = require('chai-subset');
chai.use(chaiSubset);

it('should contain subset', () => {
    const actual = [
      { name: 'foo', id: 1 },
      { name: 'bar', id: 2 },
    ];

    expect(actual).to.containSubset([{ name: 'foo' }]);
});
```

Afaik there's no way to do this with `chai` alone, but you could write your own function:

```
function containsPartialObj(arr, obj) {
  return arr.some(entry => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return keys.every(key => obj[key] === entry[key]);
  });
}

it('should contain subset', () => {
     const actual = [
        { name: 'foo', id: 1 },
        { name: 'bar', id: 2 },
     ];
    
     expect(containsPartialObj(actual, { name: 'foo' })).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there really no way to do this with the native `assert` library?

Comment: Afaik unfortunately not - I've edited my answer and added a version without having to rely on an extra library. Maybe it helps :)